# here-api : Get Adress on Positioning API REST response

Tags: php, here-api

Good evening!

Is there any way to return in the REST response of the Positioning API the lat and long and the address in the same post request like below example:

```
{
  "location": {
  "lat": -23.554284,
  "lng": -46.605026,
  "accuracy": 526,
  "address": "Rua Javari, Mooca, São Paulo, Microrregião de São Paulo, RMSP, Mesorregião Metropolitana de São Paulo, São Paulo, Southeast Region, 03112-100 , Brazil"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. You can use the [Geocoding API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/example-reverse-geocoding.html) to get the address for the location returned by the Positioning API.